# Selectively suppressing glibc link warnings?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc, binutils

glibc uses the following "technique" to generate link warnings...

```
#define link_warning(symbol, msg) \
  __make_section_unallocated (".gnu.warning." #symbol) \
  static const char __evoke_link_warning_##symbol[]     \
  __attribute__ ((used, section (".gnu.warning." #symbol __sec_comment))) \
  = msg;
```

For a particular link warning generated by this, is there any command-line switch that can be passed to ld or gcc in order to suppress it?

(For compile-time warnings you can suppress with `#pragma diagnostic foo ignore")

Comment: [How do you suppress GCC linker warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409448/how-do-you-suppress-gcc-linker-warnings)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you suppress GCC linker warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409448/how-do-you-suppress-gcc-linker-warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any command-line switch that can be passed to ld or gcc in order to suppress it

No.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's important to remember that the warnings are (usually) there for a reason.  If you can find a way to avoid linking the symbols that the warning refers to, that's a far preferable course of action.

Now...  As the question notes, the linker emits the warnings because they're in library sections named '.gnu.warning.*'.  And as explained at length in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263205/193887), there's no way to suppress this with a command line switch.

But renaming the relevant sections will suppress the warnings.

(You could try removing the sections, but the `__evoke_*` symbols are referenced in the relocation tables.  Renaming is simpler, and can be reversed in future - although of course you should back up the original of any library you do this to.)

```
objcopy --rename-section .gnu.warning.<symbol>=.xgnu.warning.<symbol> libX.a libX-nowarnings.a
```

You can link the modified library, or replace the original in situ.  Of course, whether this is possible or advisable depends on your specific circumstances.