# Is there an equivalent of link_warning(symbol) for C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-warning

Is it possible to define a C++ class method that would compile cleanly but produce a warning message when *used*, in a way similar to the unimplemented C library functions? Something like:

```
int MyClass::frobnicate() 
{
    link_warning(frobnicate, "function not implemented");
    return 0;
}
```

An `__attribute__((deprecated))` or a newer `[[deprecated]]` attribure has the right functionality (that's what I will use if there's no other option), but I would like to avoid telling the user that `frobnicate` is deprecated when it's really just cannot be implemented due to XYZ reason.

A C code example (from [glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190834/selectively-suppressing-glibc-link-warnings)):

```
#define link_warning(symbol, msg) \
  __make_section_unallocated (".gnu.warning." #symbol) \
  static const char __evoke_link_warning_##symbol[]     \
  __attribute__ ((used, section (".gnu.warning." #symbol __sec_comment))) \
  = msg;
```

The warning this macro gives looks like the following ([here's](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/iogets.c) an example of code using it):

> /path/to/file.o: In function `symbol':
>
> /path/to/file.c:line: warning: msg

A naive `link_warning(MyClass::frobnicate, "function not implemented")` doesn't seem to work, and finding out and using decorated names seems hacky and unportable (and I'm not sure it will actually work).

Comment: What "unimplemented C library functions" are you referring to? Any reason not to simply print a message to stderr (e.g. via `std::cerr`) or better yet, throw an exception? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is linker warning? Do you mean linker error?

Comment: IIRC using `gets` triggers a linker warning on Linux.

Comment: @hyde I mean something similar to what you get when you try to call [`lchmod()` on Linux](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-09/msg00268.html).

Comment: You might want to add an example C code, and the warning it gives.

Comment: @hyde Hi and thanks for following up. I have added a code example.

Comment: I wonder if you could get somewhere with `extern "C"` and a proxy C function like `MyClass_frobnicate`... Maybe not, just a thought.

Comment: can't you just apply `__attribute((warning("message")))` or `[[gnu::warning("message")]]` to your function ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Geez, I somehow missed those things. Makes me wonder why did glibc implement this in such a complex way if there's an easy way to it. Portability?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the difference is that one works at compile time (survives inlining, but not dead code elimination...), the other at link time (won't fire when inlined...) ...